# Nas QNAP 469, locked files

Tags: samba, qnap

We use shared folders, and sometimes files are locked by users.
I have connected to qnap via SSH and trying this command:

> /usr/local/samba/bin/smbstatus

It showed me "Locked files" with PID, but these numbers are duplicated in different files.
How to close locked connections to files in the right way?